# REST object to semi-dynamic .net object

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, dynamic, datacontract

I have a website that uses REST to access some WCFs.

I have this structure server side :

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class Widget
    <DataMember()>
    Public Properties As Object 
    <DataMember()>
    Public Type As String
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class PropertiesA
    <DataMember()>
    Public Hip As String
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class PropertiesB
    <DataMember()>
    Public Hop As Integer
End Class
```

And I'd like to pass objects with one or the other properties such as :

```
A = { Widget: { Type: "text", Properties: { Hip: "toto" } } } // has to use PropertiesA
B = { Widget: { Type: "value", Properties: { Hop: 5 } } } // has to use PropertiesB
```

But I don't know how to make the match between the "Type" property and the fact that the .NET deserializer has to create a PropertiesA or PropertiesB object.

Do you think it's possible ?

Edit: currently looking at DataContractResolver

Answer (score 0):

WCF is all about strongly typed contracts for services and messages sent to services. Within strong typing, there is some flexibility in WCF around interfaces and inheritance chains. Look at these two attributes to see if they can be adapted to accomplish what you want: [ServiceKnownType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) or the [KnownType attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167932/c-sharp-wcf-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-knowntype-attribute#3167994).