# How to handle Dtos for objects which implement multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, dto

We are using Dtos in our WCF service interface, but have started to come across issues when the Business Object that the Dto represents implements more than a single interface and we want to return the Dtos in those different contexts and to also be able to treat the Dtos polymorphically on the client.

For example lets say we have an interface for an `IBusinessObject` with several properties containing details of the relationships of the object, attributes of the object etc etc.  I have several implementations of this one being a `LinearBusinessObject` which implement `IBusinessObject` and `ILinear`.  There are other implementations of `ILinear` which are not also business objects, just simple linear things.

Our service has a method to get a business object.  This returns a base Dto class (`BusinessObjectDto`) which declares the common parts of a `IBusinessObject` (relationships attributes etc) and the `LinearBusinessObjectDto` which extends `BusinessObjectDto` and adds the extra information about the linear side of things.  This is fine and enables the client to treat the returned `BusinessObjects` with some degree of polymorphism.

We also want a method which gets a Linear thing.  This returns a base class `LinearDto` which contains the common linear details.  The simple linear object implementation extend `LinearDto` and all is good.  But now I have a problem, as I can't have my `LinearBusinessObjectDto`extend from both `LinearDto` and and `BusinessObjectDto` as only single inheritance is supported, and I can't use interfaces as WCF doesn't know what types to then put in the service contract definitions in the WDSL.

So I've started having 2 dtos for my `LinearBusinessObject`, one which derives from `BusinessObjectDto` (`LinearBusinessObjectAsBusinessObjectDto`) and one which derives from LinearDto (`LinearBusinessObjectAsLinearDto`) and then converting each one based on the interface I'm interested in.

This seems like its going to result in many extra Dto classes (of which I already have many) and so I'm wondering if there is a better solution than this?  Or is this just something we have to live with?

Comment: Have you looked at Ria services? It offers sharing .shared.cs files at both ends and it is easy to design dto, however if you haven't implemented it yet then you can evaluate, we have seen Ria services offer lot more features then wcf.

Comment: I don't think that is an option Akash, we are already quite heavily invested in WCF...  I'll bear that in mind in the future though.  Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A wise man once told me that Object Orientation is the enemy of services.

It seems to me that this is a general OO/SOA problem rather than a specific WCF problem: the old advice of "Favor Composition over Inheritance" comes to mind. When it comes to services especially, Polymorphic designs should not be what you are after in your DTO layer. You should avoid using DTO's that use inheritance or Interfaces (and interfaces are not even possible unless you are serializing/deserialising dynamically...you can't generate concrete proxies using SVCUtil as the concrete types are not known at generation time, but from my memory this is possible when using ChannelFactories in your .NET client...I can't remember the details though).

In general when you create DTO/DataContracts only define members/properties in them that are concrete. Your DTO model should be designed to be flat and cross platform, not Object Orientated.

Comment: If I have a service which needs to return a `Customer` say, and I have many different types of `Customer`, (NewCustomer, PreferredCustomer, HighVolumeCustomer etc) how should these be returned?  Should I have a single `CustomerDto` which has a property `CustomerType` which is an enum containing the various types of customer, and also contains ALL the properties that any of the customer could have?

Comment: Canonical messages work like you mention above,and they are advocated for SOA's esp ones with a ESB. If doing this allows you to solve your problem and move on, you can justify if this way.

Comment: In general I think MrLane is right, the problem is OO not WCF. If the OP wants to compose behaviour, he should combine interfaces;if he wants to compose data he should use composition. Sam Holder is also correct that KnownTypeOf can be used to declare inheritance hierarchies, but the OP is making the mistake of trying to model multiple data composition as multiple inheritance, which is a problem of conceptualisation and analysis rather than implementation.

Comment: In terms of the Customer DTO you have two options: have one big customer DTO with Nullable fields and a descriptor of the type as you mention (but enums are discouraged over WCF as they are not truely platform independant) or...and what I would advise, just create seperate DTO classes for each customer type. If there is repeated fields between similar DTO's its not THAT much of an issue. Its not OO where "don't repeat yourself" is a guiding rule. If there is stuff you really want as common, then sure create a general Customer DTO, but compose it as a property into your specific Customer DTOs.

Comment: @MrLane ok, but if I do that then what do I return from my GetCustomers method?  Just an object so I can then return any type of cutomer?  That's not very useful from the client perspective. If I want to return anything else then I'm back in the realm of having a base object to return and the problems I described.

Comment: The only solution I see which would fit with what you are suggesting is to have a method to return a  `NewCustomer` a method to return a `PreferredCustomer` a method to return a `HighVolumeCustomer` etc etc so each method can return a specific type of Dto

Comment: As I see it its one method with a flattened customer DTO with potentially a stack of unused properties specific to a type of customer, or split into various methods with the more specific return type as you have suggested. If you request a customer (by name, ID, whatever) that is for a different type of customer than provided by the specific method you can return a null or have some flag in the DTO indicating an invalid lookup.

Comment: Having done alot of EntityFramework myself, this Customer and CustomerType arrangement would actually come from a series of normalised tables for me. You can take a similar approach actually if you dont want specific methods: keep your generic Customer DTO, create individual specific Customer DTOs, but have a strongly typed property for each specific DTO in your generic Customer DTO. This way you wont have loads of null properties and you can easly determine what type of customer you have got because all the DTO properties will be NULL except for the specific customer type returned.

Comment: You can then navigate your Customer DTO like this: customer.MaleCustomer.SomeMaleSpecificField. All other "customer.XXXCustomer" fields should be null so you know that customer is a MaleCustomer type and the MaleSpecificFields are not polluting the generic Customer DTO. All of this is strongly typed, still generic-ish and the fields for specific types are at least encapsulated. I still like specific methods by type: you can encapsulate what is common in a composed class: MaleCustomer.CustomerCommon.Age. This is a more normalised design with no need for "null testing" to determine the type.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have understood what you are trying to say so please excuse me if I have miss interpreted. Basically you have the following objects which you want to pass via a WCF contract:

```cs
class SpecificImplementationOfA : IInterfaceA

class SpecificImplementationOfB : IInterfaceB

class CombinationOfAAndB : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB
```

You mentioned that you don't want to use interfaces on the WCF contract because you may return different implementations of the interface.

My question to you is do you actually need same implementation of the object returned to the client, do you actually need the client to receive an instance of CombinationOfAAndB or can it be something else that has the same signature. Secondly does the client ever return any of these objects and if so how does the question above apply?

If the answer to this is that client and service doesn't care can you introduce a client side side specific object which implements the interfaces in question and is registered in the clients knowntypes (KnownTypes are for deserialization not serialization)  and let WCF do the mapping.

```cs
interface IInterfaceAAndB : IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB

interface ISomeWcfContract
{
    IInterfaceA GetA();
    IInterfaceB GetB();
    IInterfaceAAndB GetAAndB();
}

class ClientImplementationOfA : IInterfaceA
class ClientImplementationOfB : IInterfaceB
class ClientImplementationOfAAndB : IInterfaceAAndB

private static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownType()
{
    yield return typeof(ClientImplementationOfA);
    yield return typeof(ClientImplementationOfB);
    yield return typeof(ClientImplementationOfAAndB);
}
```

Yes this does introduce another DTO object but it only needs to exist on the client and it means that your whole contract is implemented to an interface, you can change the implementation / swap in different objects on the client or server without any impact on the other as long as the contract is not broken. You can even introduce new properties and methods without breaking existing clients if done correctly and within reason.

Comment: If I were to use interfaces in the WCF service then I wouldn't have the problem I don't think, as the wsdl would just declare all methods of type object and I could return anything from any method.  Using interfaces in the service is not recommended and is the cause of the problem, as when you try and substitute concrete classes into your example you get stuck at `IInterfaceAAndB` as you can't inherit from 2 classes.

Comment: @SamHolder where does it say passing interfaces in wcf services is not recommended? It certainly requires a bit more leg work but that gives you much more flexibility. As for inheriting from to concrete classes that is more down to the limitations in c# and not wcf. With the example above you will not have to do any conversion prior to sending your object down the wire, Wcf can do the conversion for you.

Comment: as soon as you start using interfaces the WSDL just returns (and expects) everything as object, so your services stop being self describing and become much more difficult to use (what exactly can you pass to that service method that is defined as `SomeMethod(Object, Object, ArrayOfObject)`?

Comment: @SamHolder but if you control the Service and the Client what do you care about the WSDL. I have made the assumption here that your client is a .net WCF client which you control. If that is not the case then I take it all back.

Comment: our initial client is a silverlight client but we need to be language agnostic as far as possible, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

WCF provides a hook for defining "known types" on interfaces and inheritance chains. I'm not sure that using either the [ServiceKnownType attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) or the [KnownType attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167932/c-sharp-wcf-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-knowntype-attribute#3167994) is directly applicable to what you describe but its definitely worth a look.

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't solve our problem.  We are using the KnownType attribute to allow derived types to be returned from methods which are declared as returning the base type, but this doesn't help when returning a type which has a different base type completely I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an internal web service or will you be hosting it externally?

If this is internal, have a look at the **"Reuse types in referenced assemblies"** option in the **"Configure service reference"** dialogue

1. Reference your DTO assembly (ensuring your DTOs are in their own assembly) in the client project
2. Bring up the "Configure Service Reference" dialogue for the targeted WCF service
3. Select the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" checkbox
4. Select the "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies" radio button
5. Select the DTO assembly from the list.

The result you receive from your `ServiceClient()` will be the actual type from the referenced DTO assembly, not a generated proxy. you should now be able to act on your objects polymorphically.

Comment: Thanks Patrick I am aware of this, but I don't think you have understood the issue.  The problem is when you have 2 service methods which return different dto types (line LinearDto and BusinessObjectDto) and a single model implementation class which needs to represent both of those things (a LinearBusinessObject) and needs to be converted to either a LinearDto or a BusinessObjectDto depending on the method.

Comment: Right, I see what you're getting at. The issue is that you want the returned DTO to inherit from both base classes. If it were me, I'd probably try to get rid of the inheritance all together and try to implement using Interfaces - but you said in the OP : "and I can't use interfaces as WCF doesn't know what types to then put in the service contract definitions in the WDSL" Can you expand or clairify? if you're using "Reuse types..." and referencing the DTO assembly, what problems do you face specifically?

Comment: Yes inheriting from both base classes is what the ideal solution would be.  If you use interfaces in your service methods then your WSDL is just typeof object everywhere.  And whilst we are reusing types when it is a .net client we need to be technology independent as far as possible and so need the WSDL to be self describing.  WCF is just not meant to define its contracts using interfaces, is my understanding

Comment: It does get a bit more difficult when supporting more than just .NET. 

You're right, you do run into the problem of service calls returning object if the return type of the method is an interface - if you return a concrete type, the service proxy will return that type - you can then use it in a polymorphic scenario. This won't work for your scenario anyway considering the technology support constraints. Hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could encapsulate the base objects instead. So, you have your BusinessObjectDto and LinearDto objects. You then have your LinearBusinessObjectDto that contains two properties, one of type BusinessObjectDto and another of type LinearObjectDto. When you service method returns a LinearBusinessObjectDto it initializes each of these properties. You could then, possible, implement the interfaces on the LinearBusinessObjectDto and deleage the calls to each of the properties. Unfortunately, on the client you could cast to the required interface, but you should be able to choose which property you want to use.

EDIT: Not sure about the interface on DTO part...don't know if a DataContract attributed class that implements interfaces will be created on the client with the interfaces??!?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following Post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wcf/thread/31102bd8-0a1a-44f8-b183-62926390b3c3

This might be useful

I am Copying the Code for your Reference

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
public interface IServer
{
  [OperationContract]
  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(EntityInfo))]
  IEntityInfo GetEntityInfo(string className);
}
```

Comment: if you read the last post he says: If i write this piece of code and use svcutil my class generated has return type of object instead of IEntityInfo, which means that the service WSDL stops describing the service and so it becomes much more difficult to use, so this is not a solution

Comment: The Other solution could be define new types to be exposed from the Service and using XML serialization and destabilization technique convert the data from the internal type to exposed type.That's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use composition instead of inheritance? Failing that, would PostSharp multiple inheritance help?