# DataContract and KnowType Attributes in C# Client

Tags: c#, wcf, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# WCF: When is it appropriate to use the KnownType attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167932/c-sharp-wcf-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-knowntype-attribute)

Not long ago, we needed in class to create, as part of a project, a C# web client. The teacher instructed us to put the attribute `DataContract` above each class that will be passed.

Then the teacher told us that if you have some thing like this:

```
               A
              / \
             /   \
            B     C
```

you need to write class A in the following way:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
[KnownType(typeof(C))]
public class A
{
}
```

Isn't this completly against the idea of polymorphism? why should a class know who inherits the class?

Comment: I wondered this myself. More logical would be to mark class B and C as KnownType(typeof(A)). But I'd love to be enlightened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with C# and polymorphism; rather with serialization. The WCF infrastructure needs to be able to take something like a byte array off the wire and create an object out of it. If class `A` is an `abstract` type, there is no way that object can be instantiated. The framework needs to know what types it might receive over the wire so it can inspect the metadata and instantiate the right type of object.

Put another way, the attributes don't tell the class anything about its inheritors (indeed, the list need not include all inheritors); this is strictly so the framework will know what types it can expect to be asked to construct.

I would add, though, that adding the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes is not always required. They are available for scenarios where you may want to have more fine grained control, such as excluding a public property from serialization. Usually if the type is serializable it can be passed without the attributes.

Comment: Couldn't this all be done using reflection and a little bit more data over the wire?

Answer (score 1):

The WCF serializer separates out the concept of inheritance from the concept of polymorphism. CLR inheritance only means that the base class members are automatically added to the derived class as far as the serializer is concerned, it does not imply any kind of relationship between the two elements in the XML document. To get polymorphism, you have to explicitly tell the serializer that the XML representation of the derived class is substitutable for the XML representation of the base class.

Personally I find the distinction convenient. I sometimes use CLR inheritance without `KnownType` to add common properties onto classes without implying any kind of business relationship between them.

Comment: +1 - nice addition to what @Jay had to say!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Daniel Says, you are talking about Windows Comunication Fundation (WCF) , not web.

By decorating the class, you are telling to the client that there two classes that he must know to use the class "A", for example

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
[KnownType(typeof(C))]
public class A
{
    [DataMember] 
    private SuperClass myProp;
}

public Class B : SuperClass  {}
public Class C : SuperClass  {}
```

Please review this link for more information : [MSDN DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)