# Proper way of decorating dto class in wcf communication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have class BookDTO which represents object which will be used in exchanging data between client and service where service is wcf service have following attributes

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Book))]
public class BookDTO {...}
```

Is this proper (standard) way of decorating object which will be send over the wire?
I've seen examples with

```
[DataContract(NameSpace="somenamespace.DTO.Book")]
```

Is `[KnownType(typeof(Book))]` redudant here?

I've forget to mention that I'm introduced with DataMember attributes, so please disregard that.

Comment: KnownType attribute is used for "de/serializing" derived classes. If the attribute is not there, the serializer won't know how it should 'cast' base types into concrete types.

Comment: No It isn't. It is required and reason is decribed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167932/c-sharp-wcf-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-knowntype-attribute.

Comment: You also don't need the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: [Serializable] attribute is only needed to allow System.Runtime.Serialization.* serializers to work (SOAP-/Bin-Formatters)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create some sort of a link that the BookDTO should be desreialized to Book. Here are examples from msdn on equivalence to show you how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually when you use DataContract metatag, Serializable Metatag do nothing. This is a quote from MSDN article:

> With [Serializable], all fields become part of the data contract (unless they are marked with [NonSerialized]). With [DataContract], only members marked with [DataMember] are included. Note that if a type has both [DataContract] and [Serializable] attributes on it, it will use the [DataContract] mapping

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx

KnownType atrribute Marvin described to you in a comment to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The following class is a simple DTO:

```
[DataContract]
public class DataTransferObjectExample
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ExampleData { get; set; }
}
```

Everything else would be for special cases that we can only check if you post your whole code.