# (Closed)WCF with Dictionary

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller, serialization, deserialization

I found my mistake. I use NHibernate lazy loading. And serializer can't serialize RoleProxy.

How to get object with Dictionary field from WCF service?
When i try to do it, i get this exception:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

Stack trace:

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   UserManagmentStudio.DataService.IDataService.GetUser()    at
>   UserManagmentStudio.DataService.DataServiceClient.GetUser() in
>   C:\Users\d.kolpakov\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\UserManagmentStudio\UserManagmentStudio\Service
>   References\DataService\Reference.cs:line 64    at
>   UserManagmentStudio.Controllers.UsersController.Index(UserFilter
>   filter, String dataType) in C:\Users\d.kolpakov\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\UserManagmentStudio\UserManagmentStudio\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line
>   29    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

Service interface:

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        User GetUser();
    }
```

User.cs:

```
   [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class User : IValidatableObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        private readonly IDictionary<Role,AccessLevel> roles = new Dictionary<Role,AccessLevel>();

        public virtual IDictionary<Role,AccessLevel> Roles
        {
            get { return roles; }
        }

.....

    }
```

Role.cs:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]


       public class Role
        {
    private readonly IDictionary<User, AccessLevel> users = new Dictionary<User, AccessLevel>();

            [DataMember]
            public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public virtual String Name { get; set; }

            public virtual IDictionary<User,AccessLevel> Users
            {
                get { return users; }
            }
    }
```

AccessLevel.cs:

```
   [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class AccessLevel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual String Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267113/how-to-implement-an-inherited-dictionary-over-wcf

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the IDictionary to a read-write Dictionary property. In a data contract you have to specify an implementation, otherwise the deserializer doesn't know how to construct the object, I think

Answer (score 1):

```
[DataContract]
    public class User : IValidatableObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<Role,AccessLevel> Roles
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

[DataContract]       
public class Role
     {           
        [DataMember]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<User,AccessLevel> Users
        {
           get;set;
       }
}
```

Comment: I've just noticed that your users have roles and your roles have users. Remove the cyclic definition if possible.

similar problem here: http://devblog.petrellyn.com/?p=278

Answer (score 0):

Read-only variables can not be passed to/form a service, as they are not serializable. so you should add a set for `User.Roles` property.