# KnownType is not autogenerated in reference.cs

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service-reference, known-types

I have two types defined in my wcf webservice. `DynamicFields` and `ClassA`.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ClassA[]))]
public class DynamicFields
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (properties.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return properties[name];
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            properties[name] = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And when I add the service as a service reference in my client, I get the `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException`

**An exception of type**

> 'System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetResultsResult. The
>   InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 3900. Element
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value'
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeNamespace:ArrayOfClassA'.
>   The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using
>   DataContractSerializer or add the type corresponding to
>   'ArrayOfClassA' to the list of known types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known
>   types passed to the serializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more
>   details.

I have looked into the reference.cs file auto-generated by the client and found the KnownType attribute is not there

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="DynamicFields", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeNamespace")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class DynamicFields : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    ...
}
```

Then I manually add the attribute `[KnownType(typeof(ClassA))]` in reference.cs and it works

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="DynamicFields", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeNamespace")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[KnownType(typeof(ClassA[]))] //This is what I manually added
public partial class DynamicFields : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    ...
}
```

The problem here is every time I update the service reference, I need to go to the reference.cs and manually add the knowntype attribute. Is there any way to make the client auto-genereate it?

Comment: Why did you add the `[]`-Brackets in the `typeof`?

Comment: because I add ClassA[] in DynamicFields.properties

Comment: Try to add `[KnownType(typeof(ClassA))]` before `[KnownType(typeof(ClassA[]))]`

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267113/how-to-implement-an-inherited-dictionary-over-wcf]